# Is Daylight Saving Time?

Tags: c#, datetime, utc, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to work out given a `DateTimeOffset.DateTime` whether or not the date and time stored in an instance of that object is during UK BST or UTC.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: show us what you've done?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it is not clear what your question is, or what you have tried, you might find it beneficial to read through the following information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795314/find-the-date-last-sunday-of-october-in-asp-net-c-sharp to find the last sunday of march and october and check if your DateTime is within that span.

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554046/397817) to a question of mine may provide some additional insight into the issues.